# XSLT for parsing 2 pars XML document

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this soap answer file, coming from financials.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
        <RequestRecordAsXmlResponse xmlns="http://xml.thomson.com/financial/v1/tools/distribution/dataworks/enterprise/2003-07/">
            <RequestRecordAsXmlResult>
                <Record>
                    <Source>Datastream</Source>
                    <Instrument>TOTMKEU</Instrument>
                    <StatusType>Connected</StatusType>
                    <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
                    <StatusMessage/>
                    <Fields>
                        <CCY>U$</CCY>
                        <DATE>
                            <Item>2014-01-06T00:00:00</Item>
                            <Item>2014-01-07T00:00:00</Item>
                            <Item>2014-01-08T00:00:00</Item>
                            <Item>2014-01-09T00:00:00</Item>
                            <Item>2014-01-10T00:00:00</Item>

                        </DATE>
                        <DISPNAME>EU-DS Market</DISPNAME>
                        <FREQUENCY>D</FREQUENCY>
                        <P>
                            <Item>1740.46</Item>
                            <Item>1749.02</Item>
                            <Item>1749.66</Item>
                            <Item>1742.87</Item>
                            <Item>1761.12</Item>
                        </P>
                        <SYMBOL>TOTMKEU</SYMBOL>
                    </Fields>
                </Record>
            </RequestRecordAsXmlResult>
        </RequestRecordAsXmlResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want to create the xml output :

```
<results>
  <result>
    <tmstp>2014-01-07T00:00:00</tmstp>
    <val>1740.46</val>
  </result>
  <result>
    <tmstp>2014-01-08T00:00:00</tmstp>
    <val>1749.02</val>
  </result> etc ...
```

I tried a lot of things but failed to do it completely.
I'm only able to process one of the two nodes (DATE or P), never the two.

My last attemps was to iterate on the node DATE to get the dates (Item) then using the position() function in order to go grab the corresponding item in the node P. Like this :

```
<xslt:stylesheet xmlns:xslt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:csw-xform="http://www.compositesw.com/2003/xform" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://xml.thomson.com/financial/v1/tools/distribution/dataworks/enterprise/2003-07/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
  <xslt:template match="/">
    <xslt:variable name="_tmstp"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_val"/>
    <xslt:element name="results">
      <xslt:for-each select="soap-env:Envelope/soap-env:Body/ns1:RequestRecordAsXmlResponse/ns1:RequestRecordAsXmlResult/ns1:Record/ns1:Fields">
        <xslt:for-each select="ns1:DATE">
          <xslt:for-each select="ns1:Item">
            <xslt:variable name="_tmstp" select="."/>
            <xslt:variable name="_val" select="soap-env:Envelope/soap-env:Body/ns1:RequestRecordAsXmlResponse/ns1:RequestRecordAsXmlResult/ns1:Record/ns1:Fields/ns1:P/ns1:Item[position()]"/>
            <xslt:element name="result">
              <xslt:element name="tmstp">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_tmstp"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="val">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_val"/>
              </xslt:element>
            </xslt:element>
          </xslt:for-each>
        </xslt:for-each>
      </xslt:for-each>
    </xslt:element>
  </xslt:template>
</xslt:stylesheet>
```

But it failed.
I also used xslt "loops" but didn't have much success : the "tmstp" value is ok but the "val" (second node = P) still is null.

Can you please help for that ?
After a lot of research, trial, errors, I'm stuck on this thing that I feel simple but that is definitely stronger than me today.

Thanks a lot
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right lines, but your relative paths are wrong, and also you can't use `position()` directly in square brackets like that because you get different position values in different contexts.  Try more like

```
<xslt:variable name="_tmstp" select="."/>
<xslt:variable name="_pos" select="position()" />
<xslt:variable name="_val" select="../../ns1:P/ns1:Item[$_pos]"/>
```

The `_val` path is relative to the `Item` element you're currently looking at, so we just go two levels up (to the containing `Fields` element) and then two levels back down again (to the corresponding `Item` inside the `P`).

A couple of asides:

- The conventional prefix used in XSLT stylesheets is `xsl:` rather than `xslt:`, if you ever want to copy snippets from examples then it'll be much easier if you stick with the usual convention
- You don't need to use `xsl:element` when the element name is statically known, just use literal result elements

```
<tmstp><xslt:value-of select="$_tmstp"/></tmstp>
<val><xslt:value-of select="$_val"/></val>
```

Comment: I just can't thank you more than a big THANK YOU ! Indeed, it was simple !! I failed miserably on this but you saved my day ! THANKS THANKS and THANKS again !

Comment: @user1278819 no problem, you were very close to the right answer already.  BTW, the Stack Overflow method of expressing thanks is to (a) accept answers that solve your problems (the tick mark to the left of the answer) and (b) vote up any posts you find useful (the arrow above the question or answer score) :-)

Answer (score 0):

The full code.

Thanks for the asides, I will brush up the code asap with your comments.

```
<xslt:stylesheet xmlns:xslt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:csw-xform="http://www.compositesw.com/2003/xform" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://xml.thomson.com/financial/v1/tools/distribution/dataworks/enterprise/2003-07/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
  <xslt:template match="/">
    <xslt:variable name="_tmstp"/>
    <xslt:variable name="_val"/>
    <xslt:element name="results">
      <xslt:for-each select="soap-env:Envelope/soap-env:Body/ns1:RequestRecordAsXmlResponse/ns1:RequestRecordAsXmlResult/ns1:Record/ns1:Fields">
        <xslt:for-each select="ns1:DATE">
          <xslt:for-each select="ns1:Item">
            <xslt:variable name="_tmstp" select="."/>
            <xslt:variable name="_pos" select="position()"/>
            <xslt:variable name="_val" select="../../ns1:P/ns1:Item[$_pos]"/>
            <xslt:element name="result">
              <xslt:element name="tmstp">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_tmstp"/>
              </xslt:element>
              <xslt:element name="val">
                <xslt:value-of select="$_val"/>
              </xslt:element>
            </xslt:element>
          </xslt:for-each>
        </xslt:for-each>
      </xslt:for-each>
    </xslt:element>
  </xslt:template>
</xslt:stylesheet>
```